# word add-in debugging task pane app in office online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I recently updated my Microsoft Word task pane add-in and resubmitted it through the seller dashboard. After doing this, I got a document with a set of issues.

Based on the advice in this link (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online
), I was able to obtain a office 365 developer account.

Now, I am trying to debug my word add-in in office online. I added the local manifest pointing to localhost (https) from `Settings->Add-ins->Upload` the manifest file.

However, when I open a document and try to load the app, it is not found either in the store or in the admin managed addins.

I am also not finding my existing deployed app format in the office online store.

Can you point me in the right direction to see the app in the office store?

Also, how do I debug the app to fix the issues in office online?

Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Without providing your add-in title, nobody will be able to point you to the location of your published add-in in AppSource.

Comment: I had added my app name as "ireformat". The moderators have edited to format. Sorry about that.

Comment: Your approved add-in ( from 2015) is located at: https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104379256

Comment: Yes, I know we have an approved add-in. I am just pushing an update. I was sent a list of items to fix to approve the update. It required fixing issues for the app in office online. I am trying to debug and fix these issues. I am not able to load either my approved addin "ireformat" in office online or a manifest file for local debugging. I am trying to follow the guidelines in this article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-add-ins-in-office-online. I have setup a local secure site, updated manifest file to use this local site. Will share the screenshot soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your add-in for testing in Word Online by opening the insert tab on the ribbon, clicking Office Add-ins, clicking Upload My Add-in and uploading your manifest file.

Your add-in will appear in the My Add-ins section of the Office Add-ins window, and in the relevant ribbon location (add-in dependent) of the Word Online ribbon.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to everyone who replied. I was getting an error "Add-in Error Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again or contact your system administrator. The reason this was happening, I was using localhost in the manifest like this: https://localhost/IRAOfficeWeb/App/Reformat/ResumeReformat.html for the source location. I was getting a certificate error, when I navigate from the browser. When I changed localhost to my machine name, the error went away. Made this change for the source location, then uploaded the manifest, it works as expected.